# Why are Compact Steady and Expanding Solitons always Einstein Manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I am reading some lecture notes on Harnack inequalities and the Ricci flow and at one point the author remarks that it is important that the definitions for gradient steady, expanding and shrinking solitons hold for non-compact gradient solitons because the only compact steady and expanding gradient solitons are Einstein manifolds.

Could someone clarify for me why that is?  I appreciate that it might seem obvious.

Comment: I've managed to do it for the steady soliton now in local coordinates, maybe if someone could give some details on the expanding case, without using local coordinates as well if possible.